# How to remove lans from OSPF config

Tags: networking, cisco, ospf

Is there a way to remove a lan network (44.44.44.0/24) from OSPF configurations?
I have done this, but I do not think it is correctly:

```
En
Conf t
router ospf 100
no ip address 44.44.44.0 0.255.255.255
```

Comment: The Cisco OSPF network statement does not actually advertise the network in the statement. The masked network in the statement tell OSPF which interfaces to include in the OSPF process, not what network to advertise. This question is not appropriate for a programming site. You should ask on the correct SE site, e.g. [networkengineering.se]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are advertising your networks via ospf. If there are existing network you want to remove from ospf then below considering you already have entry for 44.44.44.0 0.255.255.255 under ospf config.

```
Conf t
router ospf 100
no network 44.44.44.0 0.255.255.255
```

If you have ospf under interface then you should use

```
router ospf 100
passive-interface default ( it will apply to all interfaces) 
no passive-interface {interface name} ( Networks bound to this interfaces will be advertised in ospf)
```